# Autocomplete of input field with a lot of data

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a search field, searching for cities in Denmark. I have an API with JSON to get all the cities, but there is a lot of data and therefore it takes time to load the page.

Is there any way that I can load data from this API after the user has typed in the field?

Here is a snippet of the Javascript/PHP I am using to get the data. Here you can see the link of all the cities too.

```
var cities = [];

<?
  $citiesData = file_get_contents('https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/steder?hovedtype=Bebyggelse&undertype=by');
  $cityJson = json_decode($citiesData, true);

  for ($x = 0; $x <= count($cityJson) - 1; $x++) {
?>
    cities.push("<? echo $cityJson[$x]["primærtnavn"]; ?>");
<?
  }
?>
```

After this I am using the autocomplete Javascript function from W3Schools, which can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

**How can I make this so it does not take long for the page to load?**

Comment: Do you have to call the API every time? Can't you store the output of it locally? and say update it using CRON every now and then

Comment: @ITgoldman I guess I could. I mean, the cities of Denmark does not change that often I guess :-) Just thought there might be a smarter way.

Comment: Only if the API allows some filtering that would be smarter(?) but never as fast as local file.

Comment: @ITgoldman and even if I stored it, it is still a lot of data so it would take too long to fetch this data, right?

Comment: Use AJAX to make a request to the API when something is typed into the search field.

Comment: Combine above answers, store data locally and query on it using ajax and only start searching when for example at least 3 characters are entered, this way you only sending a subset back to the browser.